# Passing data between UIScenes when using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, instantiation, uistoryboard

I'm using the really-rather-lovely `ECSlidingViewController` to create a sidebar for the main view in my application. All's working fine, smooth, sexy. I'd like to pass data between the two views, but I'm somewhat at a loss for how to do so considering I instantiated the second view controller using this line of code:

```
self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Sidebar"];
```

If I'd done it with a segue or similar, this'd be fine, but how do I refer to the instance of my `SidebarViewController` (with identifier `Sidebar`) if I created it in this way? I need to get at the properties of that view, so for instance, something like `self.sidebar.name`, etc.

Seems like something that'd be very simple to do, but I'm missing something, clearly.

Thanks in advance, overflowers!

EDIT: I'd point out that I can't refer to `[self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController setXYZProperty];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Sidebar *sidebar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sidebar"];
self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController = sidebar;
```

I knew it'd be easy..